# Frame Selection from keyframe to keyframe

Tags: python, animation, frame, maya

Currently I have an animated camera that has keyframes at only certain frames within the frame range of 200 (step-tangent).
For example, the keyframe resides at Frame 1, 50, 100, 150, 200

This camera is like a turn-table camera but instead of revolving at RotateY, it is animated with all the attributes (except RotateZ and Scale attributes), closing in at certain parts of the model.

Though I have written up a script that frame my model scene upon execution to accommodate it within my frame resolution, however I realize that it only fit my model at Frame1, and  when it totally screwed it up when it is playing to the other keyframes.
The following code is what I used for framing my models:

```
frameSelections = cmds.FrameSelectedInAllViews()
```

And hence does anyone has any ideas how I can script, in python, such that it
will frame my model at those keyframe, perhaps after/during the code execution or as I am playing thru the frame range?

Is it possible?

Comment: Do you want to continually reframe the camera on every frame?  Or only at your existing key frames. FrameSelected will move and change the camera, so it's either going to override your keys (and then get wiped when the animations play) or set new keys, changing your animation. Could you just step through the animation once using FrameSelected manually to set more keys as needed?

Comment: @theodox Only at my existing keyframes. I thought if it is possible to get it automated, it will be a better idea, rather than having to scrub to that particular frame and set it manually unless it is not possible to be done by scripting

Comment: Rather than doing it continuously, you could definitely script it to turn on autokey, go to your existing frames, and run FrameSelected - that will set new keys